# Frontend not receiving cookie from backend (ExpreeJS, Passport, Postgresql)

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, next.js, passport.js

I have been struggling on this problem for days. I have a NextJS frontend running on `localhost:3000` and an ExpressJS backend running on `localhost:3001`.

I am trying to build a login flow where I send an axios login request to the backend, authenticate with passport, and send the cookie back to the frontend (that can subsequently be used).

When I run through the flow, I can successfully send data to the backend and authenticate with passport (which writes a row to my session table), and redirect on the frontend. However, I do not see the cookie in my frontend browser (Inspect Element > Application > Cookies > localhost:3000). And when I am redirected to my dashboard page, I show as unauthorized from my status endpoint (which I believe means the cookie is not being set correctly). When I hit the backend endpoint with Postman, I can see the cookie is successfully sent and the subsequent /status endpoint call returns as authorized.

Can anyone help me understand why my cookies aren't being set correctly?

Backend - Express Setup:

```
const app = express ()
  
  // Enable parsing middleware for requests
  app.use(express.json())
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

  // Enable CORS
  const originURL = process.env.RAILWAY_STATIC_FRONTEND_URL ?  process.env.RAILWAY_STATIC_FRONTEND_URL : process.env.LOCAL_STATIC_FRONTEND_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  app.use(cors({ 
    origin: [originURL],
    credentials: true 
  }))

  // Session store
  const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
  const postgreStore = new pgSession({
    // check interface PGStoreOptions for more info https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/connect-pg-simple/index.d.ts
    // pool: poolInstance,
    createTableIfMissing: true, // this will create a `session` table if you do not have it yet
  })

  // 1000ms * 60seconds * 60min * 24hrs * 7days = 1 week
  const maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

  app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET || 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: maxAge,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: false
    },
    store: postgreStore,
  }))

  // Enable Passport
  app.use(passport.initialize())
  app.use(passport.session())

  // Prefix all backend routes with '/api'
  app.use('/api', routes)
```

Backend - Login + Status Routes:

```
import passport from 'passport';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { Router } from "express";

const router = Router ();
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
  return res.sendStatus(200)
})

router.get('/status', (req, res) => {
  return req.user 
    ? res.send(req.user) 
    : res.status(401).send({ msg: "Unauthorized" })
})

export default router
```

Frontend: Login API Call

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import axios from "axios"

type ResponseData = {
  message: string
}


export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) {
  
  const BACKEND_API_URL = process.env.RAILWAY_STATIC_BACKEND_URL ?  process.env.RAILWAY_STATIC_BACKEND_URL : process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LOCAL_STATIC_BACKEND_URL

  const headers = {
  }
  
  const inputs = {
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }

  if (!headers) return res.redirect(302, '/')

  const config = {
    headers: headers,
    withCredentials: true
  }

  try {
    // const { data } = await axios.post(`${BACKEND_API_URL}/api/auth/login`, inputs, { withCredentials: true })

    await axios.post(`${BACKEND_API_URL}/api/auth/login`, inputs, { withCredentials: true })

    return res.redirect(307, '/dashboard')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.redirect(302, '/login')
  }
}
```

Frontend - Dashboard Page

```
import { GetServerSidePropsContext, NextPage } from 'next'
import axios from 'axios'

type PageProps = {
  msg: String, 
}

const DashboardPage: NextPage<PageProps> = ({ msg }) => {

  console.log(msg)
  return (
    // <div className={styles.container}> 
    <div>
      <div> Dashboard Page </div>
      <div> { msg } </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  const BACKEND_API_URL = process.env.RAILWAY_STATIC_BACKEND_URL ?  process.env.RAILWAY_STATIC_BACKEND_URL : process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LOCAL_STATIC_BACKEND_URL

  const headers = {
  }

  const config = {
    headers: headers,
    withCredentials: true
  }

  let msg
  try {
    const user = await axios.get(`${BACKEND_API_URL}/api/auth/status`, { withCredentials: true })
    console.log(user)
    msg = user
  } catch (err) {
    // console.log(err)
    console.log(err.response.data)
    msg = err.response.data.msg
  }

  var response = {
    props: {
      msg
    }
  }
  return response
}


export default DashboardPage
```

Answer (score 0):

It is basically because the client side is not storing the cookie. It is an issue from backend. There will be different settings while running the project in local and in cloud.
Try tweaking like this in your session settings and check in local environment. These worked for my local environment.

```
{ httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'None', secure: true, }
```

you have to tweak this in trial and error method for cloud hosting in railway.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this didn't work for me, I tried every permutation of httpOnly: true/false, sameSite:"none"/"lax", secure:true/false but none of them worked for me